# How python (not pandas) treat NaN within a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have some NaN value in a column within a dataframe. If I used pd.isnull(), I am able to extract these rows - see below

[image]

However, if I try to use a function to assign a new value to these null value, it doesn't work - see below. What would be the right way to identify null value inside a function?

I know I could use fillna function to replace all null with an empty space, then modify the if statement to if str(x) == '' but I try to understand how python (not pandas) treat NaN. Thanks

[image]

Below is the code:

```
import pandas as pd

df[df['comment'].isnull()]
def new_column(x):
    if  str(x) is None:
        return 'no value'
    else:
        return x
df['test'] = df.apply(lambda row: new_column(row['comment']),axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a function, you can use `pd.isna`:

```
df['test'] = df['comment'].apply(lambda x: 'no value' if pd.isna(x) else x)

# Or

def new_column(x):
    if pd.isna(x):
        return 'no value'
    else:
        return x

df['test'] = df['comment'].apply(new_column)
```

but you have many other "vectorized" ways:

Use `fillna`:

```
df['test'] = df['comment'].fillna('no value')
```

Or use `np.where`:

```
df['test'] = np.where(df['comment'].isna(), 'no value', df['comment'])
```

Or `where` from pandas:

```
d['test'] = df['comment'].where(df['comment'].notna(), other='no value')
```

Comment: Thanks but I try to understand how Python (not either pandas or numpy) treat NaN.

Comment: Use `if str(x) == 'nan':`

Comment: Thank you! This is the exactly answer I am looking for.